# Upoladed File Is Corrupt After Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my webapplication. I have made an upload-function for uploading documents. one For Answer Paper And Another Is Question Paper. I have No problem In Question Papeer Its Works Fine But When After Upload  Answer Paper is Corrupt..

Any Idia

```
<div >
                  <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Attached Question File </label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuQFile" runat="server" onChange="chngFUvalue(this)" CssClass="input-file uniform_on" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblQVfile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div>
                </div>
                   <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Attached Answer File </label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAFile" runat="server" onChange="chngFUvalue(this)" CssClass="input-file uniform_on" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblAVfile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></div>
                </div>
```

///For Question Pappr(Works Fine)////
                string VQFile = "", VQFilePath = "";

```
            if (fuQFile.HasFile)
            {
                VQFile =  fuQFile.FileName.ToString();
                VQFilePath = "1upload/files/Question/" + VQFile;
                fuQFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/1upload/files/Question/") + VQFile);
            }
            else
            {
                VQFilePath = lblQVfile.Text;

            }



      // For Answer Paper(Facing Problem With That Part)////File Is Corrupt After Upload//////
            if (fuAFile.HasFile)
            {
                VAFile = rndnom + "-" + fuAFile.FileName.ToString();
                VAFilePath = "1upload/files/Answer/" + VAFile;
                fuQFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/1upload/files/Answer/") + VAFile);
            }
            else
            {

                VAFilePath = lblAVfile.Text;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calling fuQFile.SaveAs when saving the answer file, rather than fuAFile.SaveAs.

[image]